# C++ exception support in linux kernel module

Tags: c++, linux, exception, linux-kernel, itanium-abi

In 2005  Dr Dobb's  magazine published an [article](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/c-exceptions-the-linux-kernel/229100146) about patch for linux kernel. The patch pretended to allow Itanium C++ ABI in kernel space. The patch was not [accepted](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/140296-fyi-c-linux-kernel). 
The code disappeared from the Net (I cannot find it :)).

It seems that the [link](http://developers.slashdot.org/story/04/10/27/2110228/c-in-the-linux-kernel) sended us to sources of the patch. The address on the [page](http://developers.slashdot.org/story/04/10/27/2110228/c-in-the-linux-kernel) leads to [nonexistent](http://netlab.ru.is/exception/LinuxCXX.shtml)  page. There are a lot of pages that linked to the dead address.

So does anybody have a copy of the patch or any other information about it?

Thanx.

Comment: Not yet. My intentions are not so serious. But may be I will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wouldn't it be nice if [somebody](http://archive.org/) had made a backup of the internet?

like this: [C++ in the Linux Kernel](http://web.archive.org/web/20071222161357/http://netlab.ru.is/exception/LinuxCXX.shtml)